# Merge Excel rows where record was split

Tags: excel, vba, merge, macros

I'm exporting a report and the record splits into multiple rows when importing into Excel. Each report has upwards of 30K rows after the import. The only column spared from the split is Column A, each other column could be split into 2-4 rows.
Is there anyway to automatically merge these rows so that it looks like the bottom portion of the image attached?

[image: Concatenation]
[image: Export and Ideal results: Excel]

Comment: If you haven't already, I would look into customizing how you import into excel. I'm not sure what the file you are pulling from looks like, but it may be simple.

Comment: @MaciejLos I have been using a formula to concatenate two cells into empty columns, however this doesn't work for all records so I have to manually go through the entire document still

Comment: @LoopMe it's a .txt file

Comment: You can import .txt files into excel. It normally uses some kind of delimiter such as tabs or commas to know where cells end and begin.

Comment: @LoopMe I am importing the .txt file, but the document doesn't have a delimiter already inside that would be recognized by excel for the import and since the records in are in multiple rows the delimiter doesn't carry them into the same cell as the text before.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim strng As String
    Dim iRow As Long, startRow As Long, endRow As Long, iCol As Long

    With Worksheets("Export") '<--| change "Export" with your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            For Each area In .Areas
                strng = ""
                startRow = area.End(xlUp).row
                endRow = area.Rows(area.Rows.Count).row
                iCol = area.End(xlToRight).Column
                For iRow = startRow To endRow
                    strng = strng & .Parent.Cells(iRow, iCol) & " "
                Next iRow
                .Parent.Cells(startRow, iCol) = strng
            Next area
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked for most records, I added an image to the question so you could see the results where it did not work if you were curious. This has still helped me save some time though.